# How to mock a property of a service (as opposed to a function/method) using Jest

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am testing this code which has dependency on `OidcSecurityService`:

```
  import { OidcSecurityService } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';

  constructor(private oidcService: OidcSecurityService,
              private userService: UserService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.oidcService.checkAuth().subscribe(b => {
       if (b) { 
       this.oidcService.userData$.       //IS ALWAYS UNDEFINED
         .subscribe(user => this.userService.init(user)); 
       }
     });
   }
```

I am manually constructing the mock like shown below.

```
const MockOidcSecurityService = {
  checkAuth: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => of(true)),
  authorize: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {}),
  userData$: ???                  //NOTHING IS WORKING SO FAR
};

const MockUserService = {
    init: jest.fn().mockImplementation((value: any) => {
       value;
     }),
};

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
      { provide: OidcSecurityService, useValue: MockOidcSecurityService },
      { provide: UserService, useValue: MockUserService }
    ]
  }).compileComponents();
```

In my test I'm trying to test whether the initialization function of the UserService was called.

```
it('should call "initialization" if user is logged in', () => {
  //...
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(mockUserService.init).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I am getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`.

Code related to method are working just fine. It's the code related to `userData$` that is causing problems. `userData$` is an *observable* that returns data on the logged user.

I have tried returning a value, but it did not work. It complains that `userData$` is undefined:

```
const user = { email: 'xxx', name: 'yyy' };

const MockOidcSecurityService = { 
   //..
   userData$: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of(user)),
   //..
}
```

I have tried this setting the value of `userData$` as suggested by the person who answered, but it still undefined. It complains that `userData$` is undefined.

```
const MockOidcSecurityService = { 
   //..
   userData$: of(user),
   //..
}
```

I cannot find any example where it said how to mock a property. I even looked at the Jest documentation. I did not manage to find anything close to that.

Is `userData$` not being properly mocked because it is a property? The rest of them are working just fine.

Looking at `oidc.security.service.d.ts` I can see that `userData$` is actually a getter:

```
get userData$(): Observable<any>;
```

I do not know how I would treat it differently.

Comment: jest.fn is for creating functions, you don't _want_ a function. It's unclear how your test double is actually getting into the code under test, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I have updated the post. I hope to have added enough information to make the issue reproductible.

Comment: It's missing bits of the component, the whole user service, some of the test rigging. There's no reason one prop would be missing but the others are set, whether the values are mock functions, observables or something else entirely. Here's an example where I've set observable properties on a service test double: https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/blob/a2706f9c69eb3294e2711605f9ac70916c28931c/src/app/app.component.spec.ts?ts=2

Comment: The accessor signature is just type information, it means it's read-only. Again there's no reason one prop would be set and another wouldn't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it seems like you are using `Jasmine`. I am using Jest.

Comment: That's irrelevant, it's just adding a prop to an object. That's not even really testing, just JS.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I posted my entire code as it is. One may just copy paste and be able to run the code. I set the value of `userData$' directly as suggested, but it is still undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userData$` is not a function, so it shouldn't be `jest.fn()` This isn't documented because non-function properties don't need special treatment from Jest, unless they are existing getters or setters (can be addressed with `jest.spyOn` third argument).

It is:

```
const MockOidcSecurityService = { 
   //..
   userData$: of(user),
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more on `(can be addressed with jest.spyOn third argument)...`. I tried what you suggested, i.e. `userData$: of(user)` directly, but it still undefined.

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce it. The problem with undefined doesn't make sense in general, the value would be exactly what you specified, with Jest or not. It's likely that the service was mocked the wrong way. See https://jestjs.io/ru/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype regarding spyOn, it's for existing accessors, it would be the case if a property were mocked on real service instance.

Comment: All my code are present. I tried what you suggested. I am not sure about what I did not correctly set up. The class has not that many lines. The problem I am having is with the `userData$` observable. I'm cleaning up everything then try again.

Comment: I posted my code as exactly as it is in my file.